# Stop postgres.exe background processes

Tags: windows, postgresql

How do I stop these background processes? I already stopped postgresql-x64-14 service and disconnected from all databases. Clicking "end task" doesn't help since they restart on their own.

[image]

Comment: You should _never_ stop/kill the Postgres processes through the task manager. How exactly did you stop the service?

Comment: And if processes are restarting then you did *not* stop the service, because that's what the service does for you.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution would be to stops the postgres.exe background processes using the following code:

Taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq postgres.exe" /T